# Sails.js simple private messaging (pub/sub and models)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, sails.js, publish-subscribe

**My Goal:**

Create a private messaging platform using [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) with the simplest code possible

---

**Assumptions of Best Practices:**

- Use [Sails.js Webockets](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets) for realtime notifications
- Use [Sails.js PubSub](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub) for DB use with websockets
- Use [Sails.js .watch()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub/watch) to get messages

---

**My Questions:**

- Can I have a socket watch only certain new models (e.g. find where userid matches sender or recipient id) OR do I need to set up rooms? Selective watching seems much easier, but the documentation doesn't seem to support it.
- If any of my above assumptions or questions are not the best way to realize my goal, then what is the simplest way to implement private messaging using Sails?

---

**What I've Tried:**

- Subscribing and watching a socket
- Reading the [Sails.js documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/)
- Looking at the [sailsChat](https://github.com/balderdashy/sailsChat) example (uses rooms)
- Searching StackOverflow and Google for sails chat examples

Comment: Every question should be as clear as this one.

Comment: Are you trying to support only direct chats here?  Or can there be rooms with multiple people chatting?

Comment: At first glance, rooms seems to be the simplest solution.  There is no selective .watch, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, it's not clear from your question why you think rooms are not an optimal solution.  Assuming you want every connected socket _for a specific user_ to receive messages for that user, then any implementation you come up with will just be a rehashing of rooms anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way I guess it is using the socket.io implemented in sails, if I remember correctly it is simply called socket.

All controllers can be called with socket.io (client side) IIRC. 
The approach that I took is to create a model called messages, and then simply create few endpoints for the messages. If you want to use the models (pub/sub) it is possible to subscribe just to the ones you want. you can subscribe every single user to just a single Model, even if you have plenty of them.

What I used to do is do it manually, when I receive one message, i would emit it to the right client straight away. But if you want to write less code probably you simply have to subscribe the users to your model `Model.subscribe()`( http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub/subscribe )
so when a message is added to the Database then you can send it to whoever you need to.

Here's another example of a chat built on top of sails.js: https://github.com/asm-products/boxychat-old

Comment: If each client is watching new Message models, then they would receive messages meant for other users, right? I want to ensure the server only sends out the messages to the receiving client, thus selective watching would be great if possible. The subscribe() method only gets changes in _existing_ database records (it doesn't receive .publishCreate() messages) according to the docs. Does a selective watch() exist? If not, what is the simplest way to do messaging?

Comment: I had a list of sockets connected to the userID, when i was sending a message, like `POST /message/user1` what happens in the code is that i search for the user1 if it has a socket in my list(from redis) and then send the message to him `list['user1'].emit('privateMessage', msg);`

Comment: Sure, that would work, but that doesn't seem any easier than using rooms. Why did you choose that over rooms?

Comment: You mean creating a room for every user? So all the sessions join that room and then you post to that room to reach the user? That's actually an approacj that i used in a second version but not using sails.

Comment: A room for each pair of users who are chatting - just post there and the other user sees it. That seems equivalent (with regards to efficiency) to your socket list approach, correct? I'm wondering if there's an easier way such as selective watching or I guess even giving the client the socketID of the person they are chatting with to be passed to the server (without need for a redis lookup).

Comment: My concern was to chat with the same user in multiple locations, tabs, phone etc ( every socket connection has a different id )

Comment: I wasn't able to find the simple solution I was looking for, so I ended up doing what you said and made a room/channel for each user - that allowed me to send personalized messages regardless of their device, so thank you for your help!